# Gridstack.js + Vue 3 components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a gridstack.js dashboard with Vue 3 and I want the grid stack items to contain reactive vue 3 components.

The problem is that these grid stack items can only be passed HTML. The documentation states you should be able to add Vue components as content but the examples are for Vue 2 and I'm struggling to implement this in Vue 3.

I have the following code:

```
<template>
    <div class="p-6 h-full flex flex-col">

        <header class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between mb-6">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">
                    Workbench
                </h1>
                <p class="leading-6 text-gray-600 text-sm mt-2">
                    {{ info }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                <button type="button" @click="addPanel()">Add Panel</button>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="flex-1">
            <section class="grid-stack"></section>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { ref, onMounted, defineComponent, createApp } from "vue"

    import TestPanel from "./../components/panels/TestPanel.vue"

    let grid = null;

    const items = [
        { x: 0, y: 0, h: 4, w: 6 },
        { x: 7, y: 0, h: 4, w: 6 },
        { x: 0, y: 5, h: 4, w: 4 },
        { x: 4, y: 5, h: 4, w: 4 },
        { x: 8, y: 5, h: 4, w: 4 },
    ];

    onMounted(() => {

        grid = GridStack.init({
            // float: true,
            cellHeight: "70px",
            minRow: 1,
        });

        grid.load(items)

    });

    function addPanel() {

        const div = document.createElement("div")
        div.id = Math.random().toString(24).substring(8)

        const componentInstance = defineComponent({
            extends: TestPanel, data() {
                return {
                    test: "this is a test"
                }
            }
        })

        const app = createApp(componentInstance)

        app.mount(div)

        let widget = grid.addWidget({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: 6,
            h: 3,
            content: div.outerHTML,
        })

        app.mount(div.id)
    }

</script>

<style>
    .grid-stack-item-content {
        background-color: #18BC9C;
    }
</style>
```

This will load the vue component in a stack grid item but the component is no longer reactive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly what the gridstack-creators had in mind but here you go:

```js
<template>
  <button @click="addNewWidget()">Add Widget</button> {{ info }}

  <section class="grid-stack">
    <div 
      v-for="(component, key, index) in components" 
      :key="'component'+index" 
      :gs-id="key" 
      class="grid-stack-item"
      :gs-x="component.gridPos.x" 
      :gs-y="component.gridPos.y" 
      :gs-h="component.gridPos.h" 
      :gs-w="component.gridPos.w"
      gs-auto-position="true"
    >
      <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
        <component :is="component.name" v-bind="component.props" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, reactive, nextTick } from 'vue';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css';
import { GridStack } from 'gridstack';
import YourRandomComponent1 from '../YourRandomComponent1.vue';
import YourRandomComponent2 from '../YourRandomComponent2.vue';
import YourRandomComponent3 from '../YourRandomComponent3.vue';

export default {
  name: "WidgetGrid",
  setup() {
    let info = ref("");
    let grid = null;

    let components = reactive({
      yourRandomComponent1: {
        name: "YourRandomComponent1", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 4, h: 5 }
      },
      yourRandomComponent2: {
        name: "YourRandomComponent2", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 2, h: 5 }
      },
    });

    onMounted(() => {
      grid = GridStack.init({
        float: true,
        cellHeight: "70px",
        minRow: 1,
      });

      grid.on("dragstop", (event, element) => {
        console.log("move event!", event, element);
        const node = element.gridstackNode;
        info.value = `you just dragged node #${node.id} to ${node.x},${node.y} – good job!`;
      });
    });

    // this will of course only work once because of the object-key
    function addNewWidget() {
      components.yourRandomComponent3= {
        name: "YourRandomComponent3", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 2, h: 5 }
      };
      // we have to wait for vue to update v-for, 
      // until then the querySelector wont find the element
      nextTick(() => {
        console.log(grid);
        let compEl = document.querySelector('[gs-id="yourRandomComponent3"]');
        console.log(compEl);
        grid.makeWidget(compEl);
      });
      console.warn("i will only work once, fix my inputs to reuse me");
    }

    return {
      info,
      components,
    };
  },
  components: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
    YourRandomComponent1,
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
    YourRandomComponent2,
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.grid-stack {
  background-color: #FAFAFF;
  border-style: dashed;
}

.grid-stack-item {
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 50;
}
</style>
```

In my case, a missing div with the `grid-stack-item-content`-class wrapping the component made the widgets immobile.
I have also added an add-new-widget function that demonstrates how to add a new widget to the grid. The key is to use `reactive()` so that Vue will re-render the page. After re-rendering, the component needs to be registered as a grid element using `grid.makeWidget`. For this we need the component's Dom element, which we get after Vue has re-rendered with `nextTick`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use own component in Vue3 like this

```
<div class="grid-stack" :style="{ 'background-color': hex }"  >
    <widget v-for="widget in widgets" :widget="widget" :key="widget" />
</div>
```

Import your component

```
import Widget from "src/components/GridStackComponent.vue";
```

Add component to export

```
export default {
  name: 'GridStack',
  components: {
    Widget
  },
  data() {
   ...
  },
  ...
}
```

And that's all. Result can look like this

[image]